# Can you use a reciprocal condition when getting "Error in solve.default" when using svychisq

Tags: r, survey, p-value, chi-squared

I'm working on a large weighted national dataset and keep running into the following error when using the svychisq() function. The overall dataset has 7552 observations with 784 variables, however I am getting this error code for some subsets I created with 1,000-2,000 observations. The following code includes "NM.svy" as a weight data frame for one of those subsets.

```
svychisq(~RaceEth + BFDur, NM.svy, statistic = "Wald")  

Error in solve.default(V[use, use], Y[use]) :  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.34304e-22
```

I only run svychisq() to get a p-value score so would it be okay to use the reciprocal condition number of "4.34304e-22" to represent the value of p to determine significance? I know there are probably fixes to the error but since the data is weighted and larger it might be a bit complicated just to get one number.

Below is what I get when I run a table on the weighted dataframe.

[table( NM.svy$variables[ c( 'RaceEth' , 'BFDur' ) ] , useNA = 'always' )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgKlL.png)

This is usually what I get when the chi-square is produced.

```
Design-based Wald test of association data:  svychisq(~RaceEth + BF5EVER, IL.svy, statistic = "Wald") F = 10.733, ndf = 5, ddf = 1203, p-value = 4.124e-10
```

Comment: hi, any chance you could create a minimal reproducible example?  if not, could you run `table( NM.svy$variables[ c( 'RaceEth' , 'BFDur' ) ] , useNA = 'always' )` ?

Comment: Thank you! I've added a picture of the table to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for the answers. After running the table I realized the issue was that the responses weren't evenly distributed. So, I recoded the outcomes to only those I wanted, throwing the rest into an "other" category and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

No, the reciprocal condition number doesn't have any reasonable relationship to the p-value.  Depending on exactly what your table looks like, you might well find that the Rao-Scott tests are more stable than the Wald tests.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know a package that works for Rao-Scott on weighted data? svychisq() is only applicable for “F”, “Chisq”, “Wald”, “adjWald”, “lincom”, “saddlepoint” and I'm getting the same erorr message for all. I've also updated the original answer with the table output of the weight object.

Comment: To quote the help page: *The default `(statistic="F")` is the Rao-Scott second-order correction.*